# Problema al "crear" la página por segunda vez (jquery mobile - javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, phonegap, jquery-mobile

Estoy creando una app para móviles con phonegap y con jquery mobile. La programación del sitio la hago con javascript-html.

Funcionamiento:

Cuando pulso un botón accedo a una página la cual se crea de forma dinámica con .append(). Lo que se crea de forma dinámica es una lista de checkbox, que cada vez que pulso el botón y se accede a la página se "quita" todo y se vuelve a crear la lista con menos o distintos objetos.

Al acceder la primera vez sale así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si hago el proceso que sea (que es enviar algun elemento a otro sitio) y después vuelvo a crear la lista al acceder a la página, sale de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La funcionalidad no cambia, sigue funcionando a la perfección, pero cambia el aspecto.

Aquí es el html donde con javascript se introducirán los elementos:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="elMaterial"></fieldset>
```

Y este es el javascript donde se añaden los elementos:

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < arrayComponentes.length - 1 ; i++){
    $("#elMaterial").append("<input type='checkbox' id='elementoCb"+i+"' value='"+arrayComponentes[i]+"'><label for='elementoCb"+i+"'>"+ arrayComponentes[i] + "</label>");
}
```

¿Que puedo hacer ahí para que siempre tenga el mismo aspecto? He estado probando a colocarla en distintos sitios (la lista de checkbox) pero nada, la segunda vez sale sin "aspecto".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tienes que probar a inicializar de nuevo los checkbox con jQuery Mobile. Prueba a hacer esto después del append:

```
$("#elMaterial").find("input[type=checkbox]").checkboxradio();
```

No he podido probarlo porque no tengo ningún proyecto jQuery Mobile ahora mismo a mano, espero que ayude.

Más info https://api.jquerymobile.com/checkboxradio/

Comment: Ya se que no es la forma de hacerlo pero estoy tan agradecido que no podía hacerlo de otra forma. Muchísimas gracias Veronica por tu ayuda. Me ha servido muchísimo. Llevaba 2 días probando de todo hasta que al final me has dado la gran solución. ¡¡¡Gracias de verdad!!!